# Why is $E(X_1Y_3)=P(X_1=1,X_3=1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a little problem about the notation and the equation described below.

Let $X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots$ be $\{0,1\}$-valued random variables defined as follows:

- $X_0=0$
- for $n\geq 1$ do
- if $X_{n-1}=1$ then $X_n=0$ else $X_n=Z_n$ end if

The random variables $Z_n$ are independent from $X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots$ and are defined as $P(Z_n=1)=P(Z_n=0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

I saw a calculation of the covariance $cov(X_1X_3)$:

$$
\begin{align}
cov(X_1X_3)&=E(X_1X_2)-E(X_1)E(X_3) \\
&=P(X_1=1,X_3=1)-P(X_1=1)P(X_3=1)
\end{align}
$$

**And here is my problem. Why is the last equity true?**

Since $X_i$ is $\{0,1\}$-valued I know that $$E(X_i)=0*P(X_i=0)+1*P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=1)$$

But I don't see why

$$E(X_1X_3)=P(X_1=1,X_3=1)$$

is true! I am sure this is trivial, but I don't get it.

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Comment: @Srivatsan: It appears to me that $E(X_1X_2)$ is a typo for $E(X_1X_3)$, in which case your answer (with minor subscript adjustments) is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes you are right. This was just a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. But the question still stands. :-)

Comment: @Brian I see. Thanks.  I have now undeleted the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expectation of a joint random variable $f(X_1, X_3)$ is given by
$$
E[f(X_1, X_3)] = \sum_{x_1, x_3} f(x_1, x_3) \cdot P(X_1 = x_1, X_3 = x_3).
$$
For $f(X_1, X_3) = X_1 X_3$, 
$$
E[X_1X_3 ] = \sum_{x_1 = 0}^{1} \sum_{x_3=0}^{1} x_1x_3 \cdot P(X_1 = x_1, X_3 = x_3).
$$
Three out of the four summands in the above sum drop out, leaving only one term behind: the one corresponding to $x_1 = x_3 =1$. This gives us
$$
E[f(X_1, X_3)] = P(X_1 = 1, X_3 = 1). \quad \diamond
$$

---

Alternatively, consider the joint random variable $Y = X_1 X_3$. It turns out that when $X_1$ and $X_3$ are $0$-$1$ random variables, then so is $Y$. And for a $0$-$1$ random variable $Y$, you know the the expectation is given by
$$
E[Y] = P(Y = 1).
$$
Now notice that $Y = X_1 X_3$ equals $1$ if and only if $X_1 = X_3 = 1$, and equals $0$ if either $X_1$ or $X_3$ is $0$. $\quad \diamond$

Comment: Your second answer was what I needed to grasp the idea. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. I had such a feeling which is why I added it. But note that the first answer is the more general one: it works for all joint random variables even if they are not 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

$X_1 X_3 = 1$ if $X_1 = 1$ and $X_3 = 1$.  Otherwise, $X_1 X_3 = 0$.